# JavaFX, NASA World Wind: How to add a JavaFX group to NASA World Wind Model

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, javafx, worldwind

I have a group in JavaFX that contains an object and I'd like to add it to my World Wind canvas called `wwd`.

My group is called `cube` which contains an object that I'd like to display in space in World Wind above the earth.

I am able to add regular polygons to the canvas using `RenderableLayer`, by adding polygons to the layer using `wwd.getModel().getLayers().add(layer)`. However, I'm not sure how to add a JavaFX group.

I'm using Java 8 with IntelliJ IDEA and have integrated it with NASA World Wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will not work because it is not possible to add Nodes as children of a Canvas. You need to rebuild the object from your group in the GraphicsContext of the Canvas…
Have a look at [Canvas in the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't perfectly clear - the WorldWind canvas is of type WorldWindGLPanel (from NASA's World Wind library); it is not a Canvas object. I need to add a my group cube to this world wind object so that it appears above the globe.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I did not find the class WorldWindGLPanel anywhere.
Is it a WorldWindowGLPanes like [this one]{https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/awt/WorldWindowGLJPanel.html}? If yes, it seems to be based on awt and swing and there is a lot of discussion about how to integrate that into javafx and the other way round…

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: Then have a look at the [SwingNode]{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html}, it enables integration of Swing components into javafx nodes. Maybe a little of your code could attract more attention here.